# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position : invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, configparser

I am currently migrating from python2.7 to 3.6 and am not able to solve this error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 1396: invalid continuation byte

I used to have this code in python2.7

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

I understand that setdefaultencoding and apart from that reload doesn't work in this way, If I import it from importlib it doesn't work neither.

I am using the configparser to open the file, here is an extract of my code:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(archivo_configuracion)
```

I have tried some solutions but I am still not able to solve this erro, can you please help?

Comment: The "reload" trick is a bad hack to begin with.  `setdefaultencoding` is not callable for a reason.

Comment: If Python doesn't correctly detect the encoding of STDIN/STDOUT, you can override it with the env variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`.

Comment: but how to be able to determine which PYTHONIOENCODING should be? I am newbie in this subject

Comment: Well, why did you set it to UTF-8 with the `setdefaultencoding` hack then?

Comment: I was using python2.7, I was obtaining an error related with the encoding, and found a solution in google with the setdefaultencoding that worked. Now I am trying to migrate to python 3.6 and see that this solution is not recommended/feasible.